# Fail in doing swarm db migration

Tags: swarm

I had updated swarm v0.3 to v0.4.
Now I'm trying to do DB migration.

I did this command:

```
$ swarm --verbosity 5 db export .ethereum/swarm/bzz-a8a75fcfa45273cdfe27c24d87ab9c41b199d9b7/chunks djstorage/swarmexport.tar 1bf9f5ae58719120e76c546b50eb573c65cb2952c8e977351cf1c13239f8dfaa
```

and I got this result:

```
TRACE[05-30|06:58:44.760] checking if database scheme is legacy    schema name=halloween 
CRIT [05-30|06:58:45.042] Chunk 0000018d92029660945b0f1883c14def16c7b4f81c57d8b3232c243a9c0ab3bb0b found but could not be accessed: leveldb: not found, 06030000000000000000
```

I don't know how to fix it. Can anyone help me? Thanks a lot.

Here is my Swarm version:

```
Version: 0.4.0-stable
Git Commit: c3b317a4fc5e59da87b2bd2b858c038cfb4ba07a
Go Version: go1.11.5
OS: linux
```

Answer (score 1):

We know about this. Other people have reported this in https://gitter.im/ethereum/swarm

We will have this fixed in next release.

If you want, you can simply move your old chunks folder to a new (backup) location and run Swarm 0.4 with a clean data directory. You will then be able to join the Swarm 0.4 test network.

best of luck!

Comment: I have upgraded swarm to 0.4.1 and completed the db migration,  but there are many warnings in the process and some files are still inaccessible after the migration (e.g. https://swarm-gateways.net/bzz:/e53a029526d55c99ded68c4d6280d4a4d1eb71ddd798b3633e3e54125ec3b33a/). Does this mean that some nodes in Swarm 0.4 test network have not yet completed the db migration?

Comment: most nodes didn't migrate at all but started the 0.4 test network with a new, empty datastore.

Comment: I would like to ask another question: What caused the warnings like this?
`Chunk 0000018d92029660945b0f1883c14def16c7b4f81c57d8b3232c243a9c0ab3bb0b found but could not be accessed: leveldb: not found, 06030000000000000000`

Comment: @OmarHung I think that is a leftover from an even older bug where chunks were deleted but the reference to the chunk was not. The entire database layer has been rewritten since, and so there should be no new occurrence of this phenomenon now.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for reporting this. This was a bug in the migration and is now fixed. As Cobordism mentioned this will be resolved in the upcoming release (which is going to be in the next week give or take)